# Highcharts: heatmap updating skips values, hides rows

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, heatmap

My web app must have heatmap with data updating from the server. **Highcharts** JS library allows to create a heatmap easily, but data updating leads to errors: skipping the first rows, and only last 2 cell are shown.

I've tried setting `turboThreshold`, using different value, leaving axis without changes, declaring values using dictionaries, and some other stuff, but these didn't help. How can I solve the problem?

```js
// Init works well
var ch1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
    chart: { type: 'heatmap' },
    xAxis: { categories: ['X1', 'X2'] },
    yAxis: { categories: ['Y1', 'Y2'] },
    colorAxis: { minColor: '#FFFFFF', maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] },

    series: [{
        name: 'Z', turboThreshold: 0,
        data: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3]],
        dataLabels: { enabled: true, color: '#000000' }
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'right', layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0, verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 32, symbolHeight: 280
    }
});

// This works wrong
function update() {
    var data = {
        values: [[0, 0, 453], [1, 2, 625], [0, 1, 213], [0, 2, 234]],
        xtitle: 'Sum',
        xnames: ['300-500', '500-700'],
        ytitle: 'Freq',
        ynames: ['0-50', '51-100', '101-200']
    };
    ch1.xAxis[0].setTitle({ text: data.xtitle });
    ch1.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: data.ytitle });
    ch1.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.xnames, true);
    ch1.yAxis[0].setCategories(data.ynames, true);
    ch1.series[0].setData(data.values);
}

// Change the values
setTimeout(update, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>

<div id="chart1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 240px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the last argument (named `updatePoints`) to `false`:

```
ch1.series[0].setData(data.values, true, true, false);
```

This is because by default `setData` tries to update the existing values/entities, but I need to replace them completely.

---

Useful links:

- [GitHub discussion of the same problem](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8384)
- [Series.setData method definition](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData)